# Get max value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've following values in my database:

```
Column1
-----
 10
 20
 30
 05
 12
 21
 10
 40
```

As you can see, the value is increasing in the first three rows. It starts again in the fourth row with some value like 5. and then starts again in the 7th row with 10, for example. That is, it lowers and then increases again to some extent. The value starts with different numbers. I want to get the highest of each. i.e. I want to get rows with value 30,21, and 40.

Note that I've only the sorted list, It can be done with some variable in programming language but how to do this in mysql with some query?

Comment: -1 for duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027847/how-to-show-every-max-value-in-mysql ... don't post same question again and again in stack overflow. start bounty if you want ...

Comment: are there any other columns? http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?32,225340,225364#msg-225364

Answer (score 0):

I would insert all the values into another table which will have only 2 columns (id AUTOINCREMENT and Val as your values).

And then I would use this select:

```
SELECT
Val
FROM (
  SELECT
      T1.id, T1.Val, (Select Val from MyTable T2 where T2.id = T1.id + 1) NextVal
  FROM 
      MyTable T1
)
WHERE
Val > NextVal
```